# In an acoustic wave, what are the first order and second order perturbations?

Tags: forces, acoustics, terminology, perturbation-theory

From a reading of several articles like the one by Settness et al. $[1]$, there is an equation describing pressure and velocity fields to be combination of first order and second order terms. What do these terms imply?

References:

1. Settnes, M., & Bruus, H. (2012). Forces acting on a small particle in an acoustical field in a viscous fluid. Physical Review E, 85(1), 016327. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.92.043010 https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01043

Answer (score 0):

When one decomposes a physical variable, say pressure, as $p=p_0+p_1+p_2$ in which $p_i$ is the quantity of the $i$-th order the following is meant: $p_0$ is finite, while $p_1,p_2,$ are infinitesimal quantities; in practice this means that $p_1,p_2\ll p_0$ while also $p_1,p_2\ll 1$. Actually these statements make sense only when dealing with dimensionless quantities, so assume that the pressure has been non-dimensionalized by using some reference pressure appropriate to the problem. $p_1$ is first order and $p_2$ is second order means that $p_1\gg p_2$ but $p_1^2\sim p_2$ in which $\sim$ may be interpreted as "approximately the same magnitude as". You may benefit further by reading [perturbation theory](http://www.mlcu.net/679-reg_pert.pdf).